# WiFi connected, but no Internet - MacBookPro

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dns, macbook

Since I'm inexperienced with Linux I could only so much based on what I looked for on the Internet.

Basically my Mac connects to the home's WiFi, gets IP and everything it needs and... No internet as a bonus.
The icon in top right shows as wifi emblem with ? in it. Info I got in terminal suggest it works if just slow. But any update via gui or terminal, browser just says no internet connection (request timed out I suppose).

Through cable it works fine though. And my phone connects to the same WiFi no problem and has normal connection with the Internet.

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
0b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008c]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

**ifconfig**

```
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.17  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::222:41ff:fe3a:2a39  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:22:41:3a:2a:39  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1366  bytes 655344 (655.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1639  bytes 180794 (180.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1841  bytes 184586 (184.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1841  bytes 184586 (184.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wls4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.18  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::223:12ff:fe22:7ee0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:23:12:22:7e:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 104  bytes 9306 (9.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 158113
        TX packets 498  bytes 46487 (46.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16
```

**ping 192.168.2.1** router

```
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=11.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=255 time=4.78 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=255 time=316 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=14 ttl=255 time=212 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=19 ttl=255 time=212 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=255 time=220 ms
From 192.168.2.18 icmp_seq=30 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.18 icmp_seq=31 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.18 icmp_seq=32 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
34 packets transmitted, 6 received, +3 errors, 82,3529% packet loss, time 33626ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.782/162.751/316.144/115.161 ms, pipe 4
```

**ping google.com** testing if DNS works

```
PING google.com (172.217.16.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.16.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=336 ms
From 192.168.2.18 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from 172.217.16.46: icmp_seq=11 ttl=118 time=228 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
18 packets transmitted, 2 received, +1 errors, 88,8889% packet loss, time 45744ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 227.951/282.041/336.132/54.090 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Done. I didn't thought of that because I think in Windows ways.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to reconfigure `resolvconf`:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Say yes to "Prepare /etc/resolve.conf for dynamic updates?" and reboot.

Comment: Got error of it not being installed. Is `sudo apt-get resolvconf` the right command to get it?

Comment: Turns out I missed adding "install" into command. Anyway, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a wrong driver. Connect to the internet and run

```
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and reboot.

Comment: I have newest version accordin to terminal when it comes to b43 and it couldn't delete bcmwl because it's not installed.